# How to disable Symfony3 caching for dev environment?

Tags: php, symfony

I cannot disable Symfony3 cache for my project, can you please help me?
Things that I already tried to do:

- commenting the line `$kernel->loadClassCache();` in web/app_dev.php
- adding

`twig:
    cache: false`

to config_dev.yml

My $kernel instantiation in app_dev.php: `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);`

Comment: dev doesn't really cache anything... If you see no change after a executing `php bin/console cache:clear` then it's not Symfony cache the problem, but PHP cache. Most likely zend.opcache is enabled.

Comment: I see the change after executing it... So how can I get to not be obliged to execute it everytime I make a change?

Comment: Well, just like I said, dev doesn't really "cache"...  So the problem come from else where. When you click the debug bar, and then choose "configuration" from the menu on the left, does it show any cache activated?

Comment: No, it doesn't. No activated cache shown there.

Comment: As a rule, dev caches should update themselves after making a change.  Pretty much invisible.  There are a few exceptions.  So you have something else going on.  Consider creating a fresh project and then trying to isolate exactly when you need to rebuild the cache.

Comment: I created a new project, then changed the default homepage route from "/" to "/homepage" and it wouldn't find the route until I cleared cache.

Comment: Which implies you are working in production mode as opposed to development mode.

Comment: No, I am using app_dev.php/

Comment: Set __debug__ parameter value to true if you want symfony to care about cache freshness. Otherwise cache will always considered fresh if cache file exists regardless of changes in underlying resources.

Comment: Also check that __kernel.debug__ parameter is not overriden by any bundle, your environment variables don't override debug mode (SYMFONY_ENV, SYMFONY_DEBUG).